# setting xml Doctype using jdom

Tags: doctype, jdom

Can any one help me in setting `[ Doctype and xml:lang="en" ]` while creating XML using JDOM?

Answer (score 1):

The `xml:lang` attribute can be set on any Element with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Element root = new Element("root");
    DocType dtype = new DocType(root.getName());
    Document doc = new Document(root, dtype);
    root.setAttribute("lang", "en", Namespace.XML_NAMESPACE);
    new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()).output(doc, System.out);
}
```

Here I have also created a DocType, but it is pretty empty. You can change it to suite your needs by [reading the documentation](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/DocType.html)

The code above produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root>
<root xml:lang="en" />
```